# How can I map an array into an HTML grid?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid

I have an array I'm mapping into image sources to form an image gallery. At the moment it maps down one column. I'm unsure how to make it fill the other columns. Any tips would be much appreciated!

This is current output

[image]

Aiming to have -

```
[123]
```

Code -

```
<div className="image-grid">
       <SRLWrapper options={options}>
                        {data.home.galleryImage.map((image, index, caption) => (
                              <div className="image-item" key={`${index}-cl`}>
                               <img src={`http:XXX${image.url}`} alt="" class="galleryimg"/>
                               <div class="imgoverlay">
                                <div class="imgtext">zoomie</div>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                        ))  
                        }
      </SRLWrapper>
</div>
```

css -

```
.image-grid {  
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(100px, 1fr));
    column-gap: 2rem;
  }

  .image-item {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    
  }
```

Comment: "Whether to use CSS or JavaScript" doesn't make sense. One is a style mechanism and one is a scripting language. I've attempted to edit your title into a coherent question. Feel free to revise further. Also, it seems like you should be tagging React or whatever that is.

Comment: It might help if you'd show us rendered HTML rather than your templating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple. Your `display:grid` property is only applied on `SRLWrapper` component.

You need to set the set the `className="image-grid"` in the parent element of your `SRLWrapper` component and then it will work :)

`SRLWrapper.js` file returns some JSX. What you have right now is only one grid-item for your grid-container. That's why even though you have set your 3-columns for your grid container, there is only one child element `SRLWrapper` to show.

**One Trick:** Always always use **Developer Console**  `(Ctrl+Shift+I)` to debug these scenarios because we get the actual picture there.

Comment: Hope you understood what I am saying.

Comment: Enjoy Mate :) Most welcome. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS file

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

change autofit to 3 it might work

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that set the grid out nicer but still have content only in left column - https://imgur.com/a/QKGYLaq